# Error while using com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I was working on the application and I used `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` I got a very long error and my app crashed.

```
2021-05-28 17:29:49.913 23418-23418/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.a7minuteworkout, PID: 23418
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a7minuteworkout/com.example.a7minuteworkout.BmiActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Binary XML file line #74 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Binary XML file line #74 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #74 in com.example.a7minuteworkout:layout/activity_bmi: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at com.example.a7minuteworkout.BmiActivity.onCreate(BmiActivity.kt:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8198)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8182)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3765)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3968)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-05-28 17:29:49.914 23418-23418/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:463)
        at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:422)
            ... 32 more
```

On seeing at I got error was where I initialized XML File in Kotlin File in OnCreate function `setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi)`. I debug the code by removing block of code where I used `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` app doesn't crashed.

This is my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BmiActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bmi_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgUnits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/radio_group_tab_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_bmi_activity">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_metricUnits"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_tab_selector"
            android:textColor="@drawable/drawable_unit_tab_text_color_selector"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:text="@string/metric_units"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_usUnits"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_tab_selector"
            android:textColor="@drawable/drawable_unit_tab_text_color_selector"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:button="@null"
            android:text="@string/us_units"/>


    </RadioGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_units_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/rgUnits"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMetricUnitsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitWeight"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitWeight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/weight_in_kg"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilMetricUnitHeight"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMetricUnitHeight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/height_in_cm"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llUsUnitsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilUSUnitWeight"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/etUSUnitWeight"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/weight_in_lbs"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_units_height"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:baselineAligned="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tilUSUnitHeightFeet"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etUSUnitHeightFeet"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/feet"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tilUSUnitHeightInch"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                        android:id="@+id/etUSUnitHeightInch"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/inch"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_display_result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_your_bmi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/your_bmi"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_bmi_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/_15_00"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_bmi_type"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/normal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_bmi_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/normal"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_calculate_unit"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, it is my dependencies

```
dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

I have added Material Icon theme but after that showing error. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you have to change in the manifest file android:theme of the .BmiActivity to android:theme=“@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar”